# Insert one pyspark dataframe to another with replacement some rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two pyspark dataframes that has some mutual key IDs with different other values. What I want to achieve is to inject one dataframe to another.

First Dataframe:

| ID1 | ID2 | DATE | VAL1 | VAL2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | 22 | 05-03-2012 | 311 | 622 |
| 20 | 30 | 05-03-2012 | 40 | 60 |
| 20 | 30 | 06-03-2012 | 70 | 120 |
| 20 | 30 | 07-03-2012 | 480 | 3 |
| 20 | 30 | 08-03-2012 | 49 | 98 |

Second Dataframe:

| ID1 | ID2 | DATE | VAL1 | VAL2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | 22 | 07-03-2012 | 311 | 622 |
| 20 | 30 | 06-03-2012 | 22 | 2 |

Final DF:

| ID1 | ID2 | DATE | VAL1 | VAL2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | 22 | 05-03-2012 | 311 | 622 |
| 19 | 22 | 07-03-2012 | 311 | 622 |
| 20 | 30 | 05-03-2012 | 40 | 60 |
| 20 | 30 | 06-03-2012 | 70 | 120 |
| 20 | 30 | 07-03-2012 | 480 | 3 |
| 20 | 30 | 08-03-2012 | 49 | 98 |

As you can see all the values absent in one of the dataframe is present in final dataframe and rows with the same `ID1`, `ID2`, `DATE` are taking from the first dataframe. These are simplified examples of dataframes, these are much more complicated, with different columns (I'll select the important ones) and hundred of thousands of rows.

I was experimenting with outer join, but after many tries I've lost any hope, so I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Posted my answer in Java code, if you need help in converting it to python I would be happy to help

Comment: Yea, would be glad to see it in pyspark

Comment: Added Pyspark code to original answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work -

Essentially, First do a `left_anti` join to extract only those rows that are absent from First Dataframe but present in the second dataframe then union them (i.e. append) in First Dataframe

```
    Seq<String> colList = convertListToSeq(Stream.of("id1", "id2", "date").collect(Collectors.toList()));

    // Only present in Right
    Dataset<Row> missingInLeft = rightDF.join(leftDF, colList, "left_anti");

    leftDF.union(missingInLeft).show(); // Left + Missing in left
```

Update:
Pyspark Code:

```
rightDF.union(rightDF.join(leftDF, ["id1", "id2", "date"], how='left_anti')).show()
```

Comment: I think the question is about Python Spark, not Scala Spark